What is wrong with my Nginx conf? Wordpress not loading Postname Permalink articles
Latest Wordpress running on Rocky 8.
With Permalinks set to Postname articles in the format of http://www.example.com/this-is-an-article/ return a 404.
Here is my Nginx conf file:
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  xyz.com www.example.com;
    root   /db/docroot/www.example.com;
    index index.php;

    rewrite_log on;
    access_log  /db/logs/host.access.log  main;
    error_log   /db/logs/example.debug.log debug;

location / {
    root /db/docroot/www.example.com;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
 }

}

Your canonical name and alternate name are on different domains. Your canonical name is using an apex record.  You should probably considering using TLS. But no idea why your wordpress is not working. Maybe if you provided logs a description of what DOES happen when you try to resolve a permalink you might get more helpful answers.

Likely reason is:
try_file $uri =404; in your PHP location block. You should remove that, so that requests will go via FastCGI to the PHP-FPM, instead of trying to be served as static resources.

That was something I tried to make it work and bypass PHP-FPM. It fails the same way when it is removed. The fix was moving to Rocky 9, see my answer.

After many hours of trying to make this work I installed a new server with Rocky 9, rsync-ed my web root, database mysqldump and nginx/PHP-FPM conf files to the new server and Permalinks are now working. Not sure what the problem is with Rocky 8 (maybe PHP 7.4 vs PHP 8) but Rocky 9 is working fine.

The nginx config I posted works as is on Rocky 9 but remove the "try_file $uri =404;" as Tero pointed out for production so files are served via PHP-FPM.
